# How to copy HTML span attribute to excel by vba

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to copy web span value to excel sheet by excel vba. I try copy from input box which same value with span but it's unable to copy / null value. This HTML to copy

```
<td nowrap class="iddisplay"><span style="font-size: 14px" tabIndex="0">IAR/19326/8JM3Z</span>
<input type="hidden" name="transactionId" id="transactionId" value="IAR193268JM3Z"></td>
```

so i want to copy value IAR/19326/8JM3Z  from span or IAR193268JM3Z from transactionId value
 The excel vba code that i use

```
Set str_val12 = IE.document.getElementById("transactionId")

clip.SetText str_val12.innerText
'clip.SetText str_val12.value
clip.PutInClipboard
test.Cells(i + 2, 6).Select
test.Cells(i + 2, 6).PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
```

Thanks

Comment: You can replace the last 4 lines of your code with: `test.cells(i + 2, 6).Value = str_val12.innerText`. Also, I don't think `id = "transactionId"` is unique in the webpage, so you'll have to find a different reference to the `input` tag.

Comment: I have used that, but it did not work. So i try another way to get the value with copy paste code.

Comment: It didn't work because `"transactionId"` is not unique. Check my answer below and see if that gets you anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the css class *iddisplay* is only used in that specific td tag:

```
Cells(i + 2, 6) = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("iddisplay")(0).FirstChild.innertext
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but something along the lines of:

```
Dim element as Variant

For Each element in IE.document.getElementsById("transactionId")
    If element.value = "IAR193268JM3Z" Then
        Set str_val12 = element.innerText
        test.cells(i + 2, 6).Value = str_val12
    End If
Next element
```

Let me know if this throws an error and on which line. I am unsure if `.Value` is a way to check the `value="IAR193268JM3Z"` embedded within the input tag, but let's see.